# How to force all homebrew formulas to install keg-only?

Tags: ruby, compilation, dependencies, homebrew, build-dependencies

Is there any way to force homebrew to install all of its formulas keg-only, i.e. without system-wide side effects? Could something similar be accomplished simply by running `brew unlink <name>` after every formula?

The reason I'm asking this is I'd like to have a secondary installation of homebrew that acts like a sort of installer for the dependencies of a hard-to-build scientific program, compiling and installing those dependencies with some degree of isolation from the rest of my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate Homebrew installation somewhere other than `/usr/local`.  But you don't need to install everything keg-only to do that.

Comment: Yes, but the key is I _want_ to install everything keg-local to guarantee (or at least guarantee-ish) no side effects. If I have 5 different versions of HDF5 or Google Protobuf installed I don't want them interfering with one another